# GHC fails to bind polymorphic function without monomorphising it

Tags: haskell, rank-n-types

In the original code one can see that I'm just extracting an expression into a binding which is one of the basic things that haskell claims should be always possible.

**Minimal case (created with the help of @dminuoso on freenode)**

I'd like `g` to remain polymorphic (so that I can feed it to other functions that expect it to be):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

main = do
    let a :: forall t. Functor t => t () = undefined
    let g :: forall u. Functor u => u () = a
    pure ()
```

error:

```
source_file.hs:6:44:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘forall (u :: * -> *).
                                  Functor u =>
                                  u ()’
                with actual type ‘t0 ()’
    When checking that: t0 ()
      is more polymorphic than: forall (u :: * -> *). Functor u => u ()
    In the expression: a
```

**Original question (motivation) posted on #haskell IRC:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}


class Monad m => Monad' m where

instance Monad' IO where

f1 :: (forall m . Monad' m => m Int) -> IO Int
f1 g = do
    let a :: forall n . Monad' n => n Int = g
    a

-- this works
--f1 :: (forall m . Monad' m => m Int) -> IO Int
--f1 g = do
--    g

main = print $ "Hello, world!"
```

but I get:

```
source_file.hs:12:45:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘forall (n :: * -> *).
                                  Monad' n =>
                                  n Int’
                with actual type ‘m0 Int’
    When checking that: m0 Int
      is more polymorphic than: forall (n :: * -> *). Monad' n => n Int
    In the expression: g
```

Based on https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12587 I tried to explicitly apply the type to help the type-checker:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

class Monad m => Monad' m where

instance Monad' IO where

f1 :: (forall m . Monad' m => m Int) -> IO Int
f1 g = do
    let a :: forall n . Monad' n => n Int = g @n
    a

main = print $ "Hello, world!"
```

but then I get:

```
main.hs:13:48: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘n’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Part 1

### The Good

What happens when you write

```
a :: forall f. Functor f => f ()
a = _
```

? Specifically, what type of expression is GHC looking for to fill the hole (`_`)? You might think it's looking for a `forall f. Functor f => f ()`, but that's not quite right. Instead, `a` is actually a bit more like a function, and GHC implicitly inserts two arguments: one type argument named `f` with kind `* -> *`, and one instance of the constraint `Functor f` (which is unnamed, like all instances).

```
a :: forall f. Functor f => f ()
a @f {Functor f} = _
-- @-syntax is a currently proposed extension, {}-syntax is fake
```

GHC is looking for, *in the context of* `type f :: * -> *; instance Functor f`, a `f ()`. This is the same difference as between looking for a `(A -> B) -> C -> D` and looking for a `D` *in the context of* `f :: A -> B; c :: C`. If I directly have `solution :: (A -> B) -> C -> D`, in the first case I can just write `solution`, but, in the second case, I must write out `solution f c`.

### The Bad

This is not what happens when you write

```
a :: forall f. Functor f => f () = _
```

Because you've used a pattern type signature, not a normal one, GHC no longer implicitly binds the type variable and the instance for you. GHC now, honestly and truly, wants you to fill that `_` with a `forall f. Functor f => f ()`. This is hard, as we'll see soon...

(I really don't think the thing Daniel Wagner has quoted is relevant here. I believe it's just referring to the difference (when `ScopedTypeVariables` is on and `type a` is not in scope) between the way that `5 :: Num a => a` implicitly means `5 :: forall a. Num a => a` and the way `g :: a -> a = id` *doesn't* mean `g :: forall a. a -> a = id`.)

## Part 2

What happens when you write

```
undefined
```

? Specifically, what is its type? You might think it's `forall a. a`, but that's not quite right. Yes, it's true that, *all by itself*, `undefined` has the type `forall a. a`, but GHC doesn't let you write `undefined` all by itself. Instead, every occurrence of `undefined` in an expression is always applied to a type argument. The above is implicitly rewritten to

```
undefined @_a0
```

and a new unification variable (which doesn't really have a name) `_a0` is created. This expression has type `_a0`. If I use this expression in a context that requires an `Int`, then `_a0` must be equal to `Int`, and GHC sets `_a0 := Int`, rewriting the expression to

```
undefined @Int
```

(Because `_a0` can be *set* to something, it's called a unification variable. It's under "our", internal control. Above, `f` *couldn't* be set to anything. It's a given, and its under "their" (the user's), external control, which makes it a skolem variable.)

## Part 3

### The Good

Usually, the automatic binding of type variables and the automatic application of unification variables works well. E.g., both of these work out fine:

```
undefined :: forall a. a
```

```
bot :: forall a. a
bot = undefined
```

Because they respectively expand as

```
(\@a -> undefined @a) :: forall a. a
```

```
bot :: forall a. a
bot @a = undefined @a
```

### The Medium

When you do

```
a :: forall f. Functor f => f () = undefined
```

, you make something very strange happen. As I said before, a pattern type signature with a `forall` doesn't introduce anything. The `undefined` on the RHS actually needs to be a `forall f. Functor f => f ()`. The implicit application of unification variables still occurs:

```
a :: forall f. Functor f => f () = undefined @_a0
```

`undefined @_a0 :: _a0`, so `_a0 ~ (forall f. Functor f => f ())` must hold. GHC thus has to set `_a0 := (forall f. Functor f => f ())`. Usually, this is a no-no, because this is impredicative polymorphism: setting a type variable to a type containing `forall`s. However, in sufficiently outdated GHCs, this is allowed for certain functions. That is, `undefined` is not defined with the type `forall (a :: *). a`, but `forall (a :: OpenKind). a`, where `OpenKind` allows for this impredicativity. That means your code goes through as

```
a :: forall f. Functor f => f () = undefined @(forall f. Functor f => f ())
```

If you write

```
a :: forall f. Functor f => f () = bot
```

, it won't work, as `bot` doesn't have the same magic sauce that `undefined` has. Additionally, this won't work in more recent GHCs, which have stamped out this weird kind of impredicative polymorphism. (Which I say is a very good thing).

### The Bad

Your definition of `a`, even with the pattern signature, does indeed come out with the desired type `forall f. Functor f => f ()`. The issue is now in `g`:

```
g :: forall f. Functor f => f () = a
```

`g`, again, doesn't bind `type f :: * -> *` or `instance Functor f`. Meanwhile, `a` gets applied to some implicit stuff:

```
g :: forall f. Functor f => f () = a @_f0 {_}
```

But... the RHS now has type `_f0 ()`, and the LHS wants it to have type `forall f. Functor f => f ()`. These don't look alike. Therefore, type error.

As you can't stop the implicit application of `a` to a type variable and just write `g = a`, you must instead allow the implicit binding of type variables in `g`:

```
g :: forall f. Functor f => f ()
g = a
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

as @Lears on freenode pointed out, putting the type declaration **above** the declaration fixes it so it's likely some kind of bug in GHC. i.e.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

main = do
    let a :: forall t. Functor t => t () = undefined
    let g :: forall u. Functor u => u () = a
    putStrLn "success"
```

fails

but

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

main = do
    let a :: forall t. Functor t => t () = undefined
    let g :: forall u. Functor u => u ()
        g = a
    putStrLn "success"
```

succeeds.

Comment: It's not a bug, but rather explicitly called out in the documentation (see my answer for a link and a quote). Now, *why* it's designed that way is another question -- I suspect it is a mix of ease of implementation and the desire to catch typos in type variable names which, with implicit generalization on, would be very difficult to spot and lead to errors that pointed far away from the pattern signature.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant bit of the [documentation on pattern type signatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-type-signatures) is this:

> Unlike expression and declaration type signatures, pattern type signatures are not implicitly generalised.

So pattern signatures, like what you wrote, are a special case where generalization (which is the process of turning a monomorphic type `t` that mentions an out-of-scope type variable `a` into the polymorphic type `forall a. t`) is not done. You can recover the process of generalization by using any other form of type signature; e.g. instead of

```
let foo :: forall a. a = undefined
```

try:

```
let foo :: forall a. a
    foo = undefined
```

Comment: could you comment on why in https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/MonomorphicPatternBindings SPJ states that "x     = e    -- NOT a pattern binding", has it just been changed with time ?

Comment: @fghibellini There's no conflict here -- "pattern binding" and "pattern type signature" are just two different terms with two different meanings. (Indeed, they apply to two completely different syntactic classes: the former to bindings and the latter to type signatures!) The term "pattern binding" doesn't apply to bindings whose pattern is just a variable; but the term "pattern type signature" does apply to type signatures attached to a pattern that is just a variable.

Comment: Do you have a source?  cause I would understand it as "binding to something that is a pattern" and "type signature on something that is a pattern"

Comment: @fghibellini Your link serves as a source for the definition of "pattern binding". (Relevant quote: "We need to be precise about what a 'pattern binding' is. Definition: **a pattern binding has the form pat=rhs, where pat is not simply a variable.**") The link in the answer serves as a source for the definition of "pattern type signature". (Relevant quote: "A type signature may occur in any pattern; this is a *pattern type signature*.") In both cases, the emphasis is from the source being quoted, not inserted by me.

Comment: "...pattern type signatures are not implicitly generalised."

Doesn't that suggest that they can be explicitly generalised (with a forall)?

Comment: @fghibellini It might imply that to me, except that the beginning of the sentence makes it much more clear that the difference being called out there is between pattern type signatures and non-pattern type signatures, not between explicit and implicit generalization.

Comment: also note that in my answer the difference between the working and nonworking code is only in the second binding - thus the first binding actually works and the forall indeed introduces the type variable

Comment: @fghibellini Huh. If that's true, that *does* seem like a GHC bug to me. But at least here it's not true: the snippet you claim succeeds gives an error for me in GHC 8.2.2 and 8.4.3.

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/16209 I reported the issue yesterday and I also noticed that new versions of GHC reject it completely

Comment: @fghibellini Okay. I find it hard to get too upset about a bug in a 3-year-old release of GHC that has since been fixed. I would expect your ticket to get closed with a similar comment.

Answer (score -1):

If I put a typed hole in, `GHC` gives me this:

```
foo.hs:11:45: error:
    • Cannot instantiate unification variable ‘t0’
      with a type involving foralls:
        forall (b :: * -> *). Monad' b => b Int
        GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
    • In the expression: _
      In a pattern binding:
        a :: forall (b :: * -> *). Monad' b => b Int = _
      In the expression:
        do let a :: forall b. Monad' b => b Int = _
           a
   |
11 |     let a :: forall b . Monad' b => b Int = _
   |
```

Given the comment `GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism` maybe what you're attempting is not possible yet.

Comment: see my answer - it seems to be possible

Comment: ok I tried on a newer version of GHC and I get errors similar to yours even with the code that is supposed to work

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth here, so I can't help anymore without researching a bunch more.  I hope someone more educated can help.